# Deleting user by id when button is clicked on that user (MYSQL, Nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I am trying to delete one user from a table of multiple users. I only want it to delete when the button has been clicked.

```
app.delete("/api/delete/:id/", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM data WHERE id = ?";

  db.query(sqlDelete, id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});
```

The *error* I keep getting is :

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '[object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

never mind I am dumb. I wasn't calling my button correctly.

```
<button
                    onClick={() => {
                      deleteEmployee(value.id);
                    }}
                  >
```

That worked